# ASP Web API create directory on server gives access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, server.mappath

I'm trying to create a directory on the server for saving files as links, when I create a directory it gives access denied to the file path.

This is how I do it

```
public static string CreateFile(string FilePath)
{
        string Path = "";
        string RootPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");
        //RootPath = RootPath.Substring(0, RootPath.Length - cropsize);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(RootPath + FilePath);
        System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity DirPermission = new System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity();
        System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule FRule = new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule
            ("Everyone", System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
        DirPermission.AddAccessRule(FRule);

        if (DirInfo.Exists == false)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(RootPath + FilePath);
        }

        Path = RootPath + FilePath;

        return Path;
    }
```

It's a Web API, not a website.

I'm uploading the files from a mobile, I managed the reading part.

The `Server.MapPath("")` is returning `D:\\home...\\api`

It's located on an external server

I tried this code running the service locally and it worked, but on external server it gives the error above.

Also, is there an other way to save the files as links?

About the problem:

I'm uploading the file from a mobile device and reading the file from the service as byte[], and I don't want to save the bytes directly to the database, I only want the Url of the file.

Comment: I think you need access to your server to grant more rights to your web api.

Comment: @KhanhTO Im using windows azure for hosting, I don't know if there is something like that !

Comment: Have you tried just storing the files in the standard `~/App_Data` folder? Giving your website full filesystem access isn't a good idea from a security perspective.

Comment: @martin_Costello can u give a link about this subject, I never used it.

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady A simple Google for `App_Data folder` will give you plenty of information.

Comment: @martin_costello okay, one more question, can I access the app_data folder if my service is online ? or I will get the same error ?

Comment: @martin_costello I've been looking about app_data, I don't think it a good approach, specially private stuff.
is there any other way ?

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady The `App_Data` folder is for storing private data for your site to use.  It isn't a folder to use for serving content directly to users e.g. from `www.mysite.com/App_Data/foo.bar`.